# simplexml_load_file converts text from utf-8 to iso

Tags: php, xml, encoding

I have a weird situation. I have an xml file that is utf-8 encoded. When I use `file_get_contents()` and print the whole file, all characters look fine. If I use `simplexml_load_file()`, I get lots of **Å£** and **ÅŸ** and other weird symbols.

How can I make the string maintain the utf-8 encoding? Thanks

EDIT:
This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook>
<Worksheet>
<Table>
<Row>
<Cell><Data> Artrolit Forte</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data>efecte remarcabile în recuperarea bolnavilor suferinzi de osteoartroza şi artrită reumatoidală.</Data></Cell>
</Row>
</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: If all is well-formed it shouldn't do that... Can we see the actual input somewhere?

Comment: I edited the question and put in the actual xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found a fix for this. I had to add

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

before trying to print the content, even though with `file_get_contents()`, everything is ok...